# How to build a list of functions

Tags: programming, core-language

Having said that I'm no expert, I have some problems in generating a list of functions inside a loop.
The functions in the list should depend on the elements of a *parameters* list, that are read in sequence. The stripped down examples here below should show what I mean.
First I tried this (rather naively)

```
parameters = {a, 3, 6, E, 2}; p = 1;
While[p <= 5, funclist[[p]][x_] := parameters[[p]] x^p; p++]
```

Naturally it doesn't work.
After some other trials I arrived at this possible solution

```
parameters = {a, 3, 6, E, 2}; p = 1;
While[p <= 5, With[{p = p}, funclist[p, x_] := parameters[[p]] x^p]; p++]
```

But in this case the output is not actually a list but rather a sort of indexed function that cannot be manipulated as a list could be.

What I'd like to get is a list of functions that, for example can be used in the following ways:

```
in: funclist
out: {a x, 3 x^2...}
```

and also

```
in: funclist[[2]][4]
out: 48
```

or also

```
Plot[funclist[[2]],{x,-1,5}]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question contains conflicting requirements.  On the one hand, it wants `funclist` to behave like a list of functions so that we can write `funclist[[2]][4]` and get a value.  On the other hand, it wants `funclist` to act like a list of expressions in `x` so that we can write `Plot[funclist[[2]], {x, -1, 5}]`.  The two requirements are incompatible: we will need to choose between them.

**Functions**

If we wish `funclist` to behave like a list of functions, we can do this:

```
parameters = {a, 3, 6, E, 2};

funclist = Function /@ (parameters # ^ Range@Length@parameters)

(* {a #1 &, 3 #1^2 &, 6 #1^3 &, E #1^4 &, 2 #1^5 &} *)
```

Then:

```
funclist[[2]][4]

(* 48 *)
```

But we must pass an explicit argument to one these functions in order to plot it:

```
Plot[funclist[[2]][x], {x, -1, 5}]
```

[image: plot screenshot]

**Expressions in *x***

Alternatively, we can have `funclist` contain a list of expressions in `x`:

```
funclist = parameters x ^ Range@Length@parameters

(* {a x, 3 x^2, 6 x^3, E x^4, 2 x^5} *)
```

But now we cannot invoke them like functions.  To evaluate them, we need to replace `x`:

```
funclist[[2]] /. x -> 4

(* 48 *)
```

Plotting, on the other hand, does not require anything special:

```
Plot[funclist[[2]], {x, -1, 5}]
```

[image: plot screenshot]

**Academic Exercise: Both?!**

Earlier it was stated that we cannot have `funclist` behave both as a list of functions *and* as a list of expressions.  This is not entirely true.  If we are willing to damn the torpedoes and steam in anyway, it is possible to make it happen.  *This is not a serious proposal*.  It is simply a demonstration that the Wolfram language is very malleable, if we are determined enough.

We start by defining `xfuns`, which masquerades as an innocent list.  In fact, it serves as a factory to produce these hybrid function/expression objects:

```
Format[xfuns[e___]] := {e}
xfuns[e___][[i_]] ^:= With[{a = {e}[[i]]}, xfun[a]]
```

Next we define `xfun`, a wrapper that implements the hybrid behaviour:

```
xfun[e_] /; MatchQ[Stack[], {___, Null, xfun, MatchQ}] := Function @@ {{x}, e}
xfun[x_] := x
```

This nasty piece of business looks up the call stack to see whether or not it is being applied to an argument.  If it is, it returns a function.  Otherwise it returns an expression.

Here it all is in action:

```
funclist = xfuns @@ (parameters x ^ Range@Length@parameters)

(* {a x, 3 x^2, 6 x^3, E x^4, 2 x^5} *)
```

`funclist` looks like a list of expressions in `x`.  The individual elements resolve to expressions as well:

```
funclist[[2]]

(* 3 x^2 *)
```

`Plot` agrees:

```
Plot[funclist[[2]], {x, -1, 5}]
```

[image: plot screenshot]

But... they can be used as functions too!

```
funclist[[2]][4]

(* 48 *)
```

Pure evil.  *I emphasize again: this is not a recommended practice.*  This is just for fun.  Programming in this style means that expressions evaluate in unexpected ways, creating a fertile breeding ground in which bugs can thrive.

Answer (score 8):

*Because of what I consider serious overlap with later answers (either with the beginning of this answer, or the later part) I feel compelled to note that this answer covers two different methods.*

Sure, it's possible. But not quite in the way you imagined.

```
Clear[a, x, p];
parameters = {a, 3, 6, E, 2};
funclist = MapIndexed[# x^(First@#2) &, parameters]
```

> `{a x, 3 x^2, 6 x^3, E x^4, 2 x^5}`

This looks right, just like your list, but they aren't functions so you can't evaluate them the way you hoped to. Instead we have to do something like

```
With[{x = 4}, Evaluate@funclist[[2]]]
```

> `48`

where `Evaluate` is needed because that rewrites the expression so that `x` appears explicitly. `With` will only replace symbols that appear explicitly in the expression in its body. This is also needed to plot any of the expressions because, again, `x` has appear explicitly:

```
Plot[Evaluate@funclist[[2]], {x, -1, 5}]
```

[image: Plot example]

You can write a list of functions that will execute the way you want, but the list won't look the way it does in your example. You could do it like this:

```
funclist = MapIndexed[Function[{x}, # x^(First@#2)] &, parameters]
```

> ```
> {Function[{x}, a x^First[{1}]], Function[{x}, 3 x^First[{2}]],  
>  Function[{x}, 6 x^First[{3}]], Function[{x}, E x^First[{4}]],  
>  Function[{x}, 2 x^First[{5}]]}
> ```

```
funclist[[2]][4]
```

> `48`

And for the plot:

```
Plot[funclist[[2]][x], {x, -1, 5}]
```

**EDIT**: As seismatica pointed out to me, using `Evaluate` inside `funclist` makes the output better looking:

```
funclist = MapIndexed[Function[{x}, Evaluate[# x^(First@#2)]] &, parameters]
```

> `{Function[{x}, a x], Function[{x}, 3 x^2], Function[{x}, 6 x^3],
>   Function[{x}, E x^4], Function[{x}, 2 x^5]}`

Comment: I was probably the first one to upvote your answer. Before you find further "overlaps": What's with `Plot[Evaluate@funclist[[1]], {x, -1, 5}]` ???

Comment: @eldo Thanks for the vote. That's what I need to make it work, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

There is also a solution without the need for Evaluate.

```
parameters = {a, 3, 6, E, 2};
funclist = Table[p #^e & /. {p -> parameters[[n]], e -> n}, {n, 1, 5}];
```

The # and & are abbreviations for building pure functions. # stands for the varaible and & has to be put at the end of the expression to build a function.

Then you can use funclist like this:

```
funclist[[2]][4]
(* 48 *)
```

or

```
Plot[funclist[[2]][x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating a list of functions, I would simply use

```
func[p_][x_] := parameters[[p]] x^p
```

To avoid accidental modification of `parameters`, I might use

```
func`parametes = {...};
func[p_][x_] := func`parameters[[p]] x^p
```

Then you can use `func[1]` as a function, or if you really need them stored in a list, `func /@ Range[5]` gives you that.

Definitions of the form `f[...][...]...[...] := ...` (i.e. having more than one `[...]`) are called *sub-value definitions*.

Comment: `func[5][x]` functions with me. `But `func /@ Range[5]` doesn't. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

```
para = {a, 3, 6, E, 2};

fun = Map[para[[#]] x^# &, Range @ 5]
```

> {a x, 3 x^2, 6 x^3, E x^4, 2 x^5}

```
Plot[
 Evaluate @ Map[fun[[#]] /. a -> 700 &, Range @ 5],
 {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Green, Blue, Orange},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest (to make easier) to do it like this:

```
 parameters = {a, 3, 6, E, 2};
    funclist[x_]=# x^Range[Length[#]] &[parameters]
    (*{a x, 3 x^2, 6 x^3, E x^4, 2 x^5}*)
    funclist[4][[2]]
    (*48*)
    Plot[funclist[x][[2]],{x,-1,5}]
```